# Integration problem in polar

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

How to integrate double integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\!\int_{0}^{2\pi}\   \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)g_m \bar{g_n}   , d\theta dr$$ 
where $$g_a=(x+iy)^a$$ . I do not know how to differentiate  first part of integral.

Comment: are you sure it's not supposed to be $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y})$?

Comment: no it is 1/2...